# Error when trying to edit a node in a Range: InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple text editor for my blog.
It involves clicking a button to add style to text.
The click will trigger getting the selection, and looking the nodes in it and surrounding them with a tag.

I seem to get an error: `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable` if I apply both bold and italics to the last word. I am not sure why this is happening, nor how to debug it. Does anyone have tips? It seems to happen when I apply a style on the last word more than once. I am looking into it now but am unsure.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sc5axhq/6/) for this question.

Comment: Well, you can `console.log` on every step. For example, i got an error on this line: `let range  = sel.getRangeAt(0); console.log(range);` which says `Index 0 is not valid ...`

Comment: Yeah already have and I do not get the same error as you.